Homebrew Vim not sourcing ~/.vimrc after iTerm, MacOS updates
I am using vim installed via homebrew:
> which vim
/opt/homebrew/bin/vim

> vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled May 09 2024 07:15:02)
macOS version - arm64
Included patches: 1-400
Compiled by Homebrew
...
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "~/.config/vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/homebrew/share/vim"
...

I recently updated iTerm2 and MacOS:
I am now using iTerm2 build 3.5.0

I am now on MacOS Sonoma 14.5

All of a sudden my ~/.vimrc doesn't seem to be sourcing properly.  Notably, when I start vim, my cursorline is underlined.  When I execute :source ~/.vimrc, the underline disappears, as expected.  Relevant settings in my .vimrc are:
set notermguicolors
set t_Co=16

set cursorlineopt=both
set cursorline

set background=dark
colorscheme default
syntax on

highlight clear CursorLine
highlight clear Todo
highlight signcolumn ctermbg=8
highlight statuslinenc ctermbg=3 ctermfg=8
highlight matchparen ctermbg=1 ctermfg=7
highlight diffchange ctermbg=0
highlight difftext ctermfg=8

Also worth noting that most of my settings seem to load just fine.  There are just some minor syntax highlighting changes that happen when I manually source ~/.vimrc (e.g. brackets and parens change color)
Other noteworthy things: these env vars don't seem to be set?
> echo $VIM

> echo $VIMRUNTIME

>

Prior to updating, my .vimrc sourced just fine at start up.
Inspecting output from vim -V has me thinking it's to do with who is setting highlights most recently.  But still not sure why it's behaving differently than it used to.
Any suggestions on how to debug this?  Thanks!

Do you have the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable defined (In iTerm what is the result of echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME)

What is the value of the $HOME environment variable?

$VIM and $VIMRUNTIME are only set in Vim. Do :echo $VIM and :echo $VIMRUNTIME in Vim and add their output to your question, as well as the output of :echo $HOME and :echo $MYVIMRC.

This probably depends on when you call a :syntax or :colorscheme command.

@D.BenKnoble edited OP to show syntax and colorscheme invocations - they're in that order at the very end of vimrc.

Please don't put "EDIT" markers in the text; restructure the body as necessary to make it one coherent whole. Provide one single minimal vimrc that reproduces the issue: I see two codeblocks, one with cursorline options and one without. Can you [edit] to make them one example?

FWIW, I set the colorscheme after :syntax enable.

@D.BenKnoble noteworthy that if I comment out set t_Co=16, no change happens after running :source ~/.vimrc - so it seems that t_Co is a crucial setting and for some reason it's not being set when I want it to.  Output of :echo $t_Co is 256 when first opening Vim; after the manual source, it's 16 as desired.

I was able to solve this by setting the iTerm2 terminal reporting type to ansi as opposed to xterm or xterm-256color.
I don't know why set t_Co=16 wouldn't force vim to use 16 colors even if iTerm is xterm-256color but I'll stick with ansi for now.

In recent version of Vim the $XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable is now supported.
On Unix systems if you have $XDG_CONFIG_HOME defined the first vimrc path considered is now: $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc

What makes you think that environment variable is involved?

To be honest I have a doubt :-| The OP is about macOS that should not be impacted by the recent XDG support in Vim. But XDG support is a recent addition that impact the search for vimrc file.

No. $HOME/.config/vim/vimrc is tried after $HOME/.vimrc and $HOME/.vim/vimrc, and only the first one is sourced anyway.
